# How Insert a line break into the Replacment string in perl

Tags: perl

I got a situation where I need to search for following string pattern and modify them by inserting new string and new lines.

e.g.
search for following pattern:

```
<start_date>2015-07-21T23:16:13Z</start_date>
<Exec>
```

and replace to

```
</start_date>\n</Compilation>\n<Exec>
```

so this is the command I used which is not working:

```
perl -i.bak -p -e 's#\<\/start_date\>\\n\<Exec\>#\<\/start_date\>\\n\<\/Compilation\>\\n\<Exec\>#gi'
```

Is there any better way? Please point me where I'm doing wrong.

Edit: I tried following code instead of one line-commander but still not working:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

my $file = <*.xml>;
open (XML, "<$file") || die "file dose not exist\n";
open (NXML, ">nfile");
my @lines =<XML>;

foreach my $line (@lines) {
        $line =~ s|<start_date>.*</start_date>\n<Exec>|</start_date>\n</Compilation>\n<Exec>|ms;
        print NMXL $line;
}

close XML;
close NMXL;
unlink ("$file");
rename ("nfile", $file);
unlink ("nfile");
```

Following code works well: @buff @TLP, thanks a lot for your supports. I really learned valued information from you guys.

```
$/ = undef; # buff's suggestion.
open (XML, "<$file");
open (NXML, ">file");
my @lines=<XML>;
foreach my $line (@lines) {

        $line =~ s/(PC\d+")/$1 tag="$tagname"/gi;
        $line =~ s#</start_date>\n<Exec>#</start_date>\n</Compilation>\n<Exec>#gi; # buff's suggestion.
        print NXML $line;   
}
```

Comment: You are using way too many backslashes, I don't think any of them are required and the one before `\n` is wrong. `s#</start_date>\n<Exec>#</start_date>\n</Compilation>\n<Exec>#gi` should suffice.

Comment: You are going wrong by attempting to parse XML with regexes. Use an XML parser.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your approach:

You are using `perl -p` which reads the input line by line and applies the code to each line. Therefore you are trying to match the one line to multiline pattern. You can slurp the whole file and work with it like this:

```
perl -e '
    $/ = undef;
    my $string = <>;
    #here you modify the string
    print $string' < input_file > modified_file
```

Your regex is wrong: to match the input, you need something like this:

```
s|<start_date>.*</start_date>\n<Exec>|</start_date>\n</Compilation>\n<Exec>|gi
```

This would do what you wrote you wanted to do, but I suspect you only want to replace the `</start_date>` with `</start_date>\n</Compilation>`. If this is the case, this might work for you:

```
perl -i.bak -p -e 's#</start_date>#</start_date>\n</Compilation>#;'
```

If you only want to replace `</start_date>` followed by `<Exec>`, use the variant with slurp and the regex provided by @TLP in comments:

```
perl -e '
    $/ = undef;
    my $string = <>;
    $string =~ s#</start_date>\n<Exec>#</start_date>\n</Compilation>\n<Exec>#gi;
    print $string' < input_file > modified_file
```

Or save it as a script (e.g. fixxml.pl):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;
my $string = <>;
$string =~ s#</start_date>\n<Exec>#</start_date>\n</Compilation>\n<Exec>#gi;
print $string;
```

Then you run it as `perl fixxml.pl input.xml > output.xml`

Finally, use a proper XML library if possible.

Comment: You can use `-0777` to slurp the file on the command line. Then you could also use lookaround assertions for the insertion of text. E.g. `perl -0777 -pe's#(?<=</start_date>\n)(?=<Exec>)#</Compilation>\n#gi' input > output`

Comment: thanks, but i have to look for `</start_date>\n<Exec>` pattern only because `</start_date>`  will effect the other lines.

Comment: Thx @TLP for the comment, I learned something! :-) However, I'm getting "Variable length lookbehind not implemented" error when trying your code. Adding `/aa` modifier helped.

Comment: @praneeth: Try the @TLP's solution, it works and only affects `</start_date>` followed by `<Exec>`, not other lines.

Comment: @TLP thanks a lot, it works. could you please elaborate your code, it looks complicated.

Comment: @buff: thanks for your help. I tired it works on one-line commander. i'm trying to convert same to script code.

Comment: @praneeth: If you put everything between apostrophes from the last block in the answer into the script file, you are done. (Plus you can replace the regexp with the TLP's one.)

Comment: @buff The `(?<= ... )` cannot contain any quantifiers which allows variable length strings, for example `foo...` is ok, but `foo.+` is not.

Comment: @praneeth It's basically the same regex as yours, but using [look-around assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions). The benefit of these is that they are zero-length, and therefore does not consume the part of the string they match. Other than that, it works as a regular regex. The point between the `(?<=...)` and the `(?=...)` is where your replacement text will be inserted

Comment: @TLP: I know. But I ran exactly your code which doesn't seem to have variable length strings and still got the error. Maybe because newline can be one or two bytes? I'm afraid we are getting offtopic here. :-)

Comment: @buff The regex works for me, and `\n` is just one character. What OS and perl version are you running?

Comment: @TLP Ubuntu 14.04, Perl 5.18.2

Comment: @buff Strange. Well, you can always replace the look-behind `(?<=...)` with `\K`, since your Perl version allows it. E.g. `s#</start_date>\n\K ...`

Comment: @buff thank you so much, i tried as you suggested "putting all answer block to script and replaced with TLP's regex" but still not working.

Comment: @buff thanks a lot. It works, i want to insert this code into other script,where i do other substitution for same file. so if try your code there its not working. i have posted the code in my question block.

Comment: @buff, hoops!!! sorry. i had a typo when i tired the code which i placed in question block. actually this code works well . Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. If you're done, please accept the answer. Thanks!